# How to set multiple selected values for Select field type programmatically?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a field `my-field`

Type of `my-field` is **Select**

Field property `Allow multiple` is enabled.

Available values of the field are

- value-1
- value-2
- value-3

If I update field manually and then the call function

```
get_field( 'my-field', 'option' );
```

I've got

```
[
    0 =>
        [
            'value' => 'value-1',
            'label' => 'value-1',
        ],
    1 =>
        [
            'value' => 'value-2',
            'label' => 'value-2',
        ],
];
```

#### Attempt 1

If I try to update field - I call function `update_field` this way

```
$update_result_multiple = update_field(
    'my-field',
    [
        0 =>
            [
                'value' => 'value-1',
                'label' => 'value-1',
            ],
        1 =>
            [
                'value' => 'value-2',
                'label' => 'value-2',
            ],
        2 =>
            [
                'value' => 'value-2',
                'label' => 'value-3',
            ],
    ],
    'option'
);
```

I've got `update_result_multiple` is `false` and all values become unselected

#### Attempt 2

If I try this way - selected value has been updated successfully.

```
$update_result = update_field(
    'my-field',
    [
        'value' => 'value-1',
        'label' => 'value-1',
    ],
    'option'
);
```

#### The problem is

I can't update `Select` field by setting selected multiple values.

Only manually I could set selected multiple values.
But can't with `update_field` function

#### The question is

How to set selected multiple values for **Select** field type with `update_field` function?

Comment: Is the name of your field appended with `[]`, eg: `<select name="my-field[]" >`? This will save the mutiple values as array.

Comment: I use only PHP without HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the way to solve the problem.

I've called `get_fields` with third argument *formatted-value* = `false`.

This gives me the clue to understand right format.

Then I've called `update_field` this way

```
$update_result_multiple = update_field(
    'my-field',
    ['value-1', 'value-2', 'value-3'],
    'option'
);
```

And field successfully updated.

Answer (score 1):

Or also you can use by this method too.

```php
// Save a checkbox or select value.
$field_name = "my-field";
    
$value = array("value-1", "value-2", "value-3");
    
update_field( $field_name , $value, 'option' )
```

for more information please check [the `update_field` documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/)